# How to prevent double object deletion using smart pointers?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, memory-management, smart-pointers

I have a class which takes ownership of it's children:

```
class Child
{
public:
    Child() {}
    ~Child() {}
};

class Parent : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Parent(QObject *parent = 0): QObject(parent) {}
    ~Parent()
    {
        qDeleteAll(m_children);
    }
    void addChild(Child *ch)
    {
        m_children.append(ch);
    }    
private:
    QList<Child *> m_children;    
};
```

`Child` instances added to the `Parent` class using `addChild` method will get deleted when `Parent` gets deleted.

Following usage will cause a double child destruction:

```
int main()
{
    {
        Parent father;
        Child child;
        father.addChild( &child );
    }
    //child is out of scope now and gets destroyed
    //father gets destroyed too
    //father's destructor deletes child AGAIN!
    //crash!
    return 0;
}
```

How to prevent this by using smart pointers? `QPointer` is available for `QObject` inherited classes which makes it useless for this case. How else can I prevent this?

Comment: **Design** -- which is the answer to most lifetime questions. Lifetime of objects and ownership are basic parts of a design.

Comment: could you please suggest a design for `Parent` and `Child` classes. remember that `Parent` class should allow modifying children such as add,remove,edit in my design `Parent` class also has a method which returns `m_children` .

Comment: wuqiang provided one approach that is probably the simplest one, not passing ownership around is a different one (pass a reference, copy internally) --although nothing is truly fool proof, never underestimate the power of foolishness.

Answer (score 5):

It's not about double destruction.You cann't delete a stack object.
Instead,You should allocate it in the heap:

```
Parent father;
Child* child = new Child();
father.addChild( child );
```

Comment: I know this is the correct way of using `Parent` class. But I'm looking for a way to change the `Parent` class design to make it foolproof! so if stupid users did what I explained everything works fine.

Comment: @user3559463, for foolproof design avoid using pointers and pass arguments by value or by const references.

Comment: but sometimes you have to accept and pass pointers for example when `Child` is large enough, sending it by value is not a good solution. I want accept pointers and become aware if they were destructed.

Comment: You could consider taking a `unique_ptr` as argument if you want this to be a bit more robust, but I am not sure whether it makes all that sense (the race against foolishness is one that can never be won)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [constructor of QObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#QObject), you'll notice that it takes a QObject as a parent, so rather than reinventing the wheel, unless you're already using it (which it appears that you're not), you can use Qt's parent child hierarchy: -

```
Parent* parent = new Parent;
Child* Child1 = new Child(parent);
```

You can then retrieve the list of the parent's [children](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#children) as required and don't have to worry about managing the children, as they're removed when their parent is deleted.

If you want to set a child's parent after its creation, you can call the child's [setParent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#setParent) function.

Comment: `Parent` and `Child` classes here are different from `QObject` parent/child system. Think of `Parent` as Customer class and `Child` as Order.

Comment: Fair enough, though your question would be improved if it stated this fact.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `std::tr1::shared_pointer` [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c15361/A-TR1-Tutorial-Smart-Pointers.htm) is a tutorial for that. If thats not available in your compiler you can use `boost::shared_pointer`, described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) Also you can [implement](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15351/Implementing-a-simple-smart-pointer-in-c) your own smart pointers.

Comment: This changes the ownership semantics completely, `shared_ptr` is too often abused as a shortcut to thinking and designing...

Answer (score 0):

I guess your first problem is about ownership of the child element.
If you want the Parent class to handle the Child lifetime, you can solve it using smart pointers.

```
class Parent : public QObject
{
    using ptr = std::shared_ptr<Child>;
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Parent(QObject *parent = 0): QObject(parent) {}

    void addChild(const ptr& ch)
    {
        m_children.append(ch);
    }    
private:
    QList<ptr> m_children;    
};
```

and then:

```
{
    Parent father;
    auto child = std::make_shared<Child>();
    father.addChild( child );
}
```

If you want to keep the actual usage, then you'll have to make copies, and store those copies.

Comment: I guess usage should be `auto child = std::make_shared<Child>();`

Answer (score 0):

`Parent` takes ownership of `Child` where it should not in your sample.

Possible solutions include:

- `Child` should remove itself from it parent in its destructor to prevent the bad deletion.
- Modify `Parent` interface to explictly force ownership transfert: `void addChild(std::share_ptr<Child> ch)` or `void addChild(std::unique_ptr<Child> ch)`.
- Maintain 2 containers in `Parent`, one with ownership, and one without ownership.

Comment: your answer is good because includes more solutions, you could add other solutions suggested by @wuqiang and passing `Child` by value suggested by @vahancho and others. I could implement `std::share_ptr` the way @Kiroxas suggested but @Lourens Coetzer mentioned that `Child` could survive after `Parent`, does the same goes with `std::unique_ptr`? can you give a working snippet using `std::unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using std::shared_ptr:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>
    #include <vector>

    class Child
    {
        public:
            Child(std::string name) 
            {
                name_ = name;
            }
            ~Child() 
            {
                std::cout << "~Child: " << name_ << std::endl;  
            }
        private:
            std::string name_;
    };

    class Parent 
    {
        public:

            ~Parent()
            {
                std::cout << "~Parent" << std::endl;    
            }

            void addChild(std::shared_ptr<Child> ch)
            {
                m_children.push_back(ch);
            }    
        private:
            std::vector <std::shared_ptr<Child> >  m_children;    
    };



    int main()
    {

        std::shared_ptr<Child> john (new Child("John")); 
        std::cout << "John created" << std::endl;

        {
            Parent father;

            {
                std::shared_ptr<Child> jack ( new Child("Jack")); 
                std::cout << "Jack created" << std::endl;
                father.addChild( john );
                father.addChild( jack );
                std::cout << "added John and Jack to father" << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << "jack left scope" << std::endl;
            // jack is out of scope now but since it's a smart pointer 
            // and father still holds a reference to the memory it 
            // referred to that memory is still allocated.
        }
        std::cout << "father left scope" << std::endl;
        // father gets destroyed here and with it its m_children.  
        // As the list goes so does the last reference to the memory 
        // allocated for child and the child gets destroyed.  
        // Note that jack doesn't get destroyed here. Even though it was 
        // one of the children.  The reason is that the orphan smart 
        // pointer is still in scope.

        return 0;

}
```

NOTE: This does not give Parent control over the life cycle of it's children.  A Parent object can be associated to Child objects but a Child object now only gets destroyed when the last reference to it gets destroyed. It is possible for a child to 'survive' all its parents if something else holds on to a smart pointer to it as in the case of john shown above. If your intention is for a Child to only ever belong to one Parent and to be destructed with it's Parent you should encapsulate the Child creation logic in the Parent so that Child object can only be created by Parent objects.

Comment: just like @Kiroxas answer but more explanations, thanks